# jQuery Datatables rendered with django ordering not working

Tags: jquery, django, datatables, datatables-1.10

I can't seem to get this table to order on click. The app is retrieving a table from Django and rendering it successfully.  But when I go ahead and click the arrows at the top of the table columns, a box says 'processing' but no reordering happens.  When I disable `serverSide` programmatically so that it should only happen the first time, the ajax call happens anyway.

```
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
        var table = $('#{{ grid_id }}').DataTable({
            "paging": {{paging}}
            ,"searching": false
            ,"info": true
            ,"stateSave": false
            ,"orderable": true
            ,"ordering": true
            ,"processing": true
            ,"serverSide": true
            {% if ajax_url is not None %}
            ,"ajax": {
                /* "type": "POST", */
                "url": "{{ ajax_url }}",
                "dataSrc": "results",
                "data": function (d) {
                    d.customParam = "custom";
                }
            }{% endif %}{% if column_list is not None %}
            ,"columns": [
                {% for col in column_list %} { "title":"{{ col.title }}", "data": "{{ col.data }}"
                {% if col.href is not None %}, fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) { $(nTd).html("<a href='{{col.href}}"+oData.{{ col.href_data_attr }}+"'>"+oData.{{ col.data }}+"</a>");}{% endif %}
                },{% endfor %}
            ]
            {% endif %}
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just to check: When using server-side processing, it is the server which provides the sorting logic (and paging and filtering logic), not DataTables. Is your Django app doing that?

Comment: so if I retrieve the data initially from the server, can I not change it to use dataTables sorting on subsequent rerenders by changing the serverSide prop to false?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't change a DataTable's `serverSide` option, once the DataTable has been initialized (there is no such API call). You have to [destroy](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) the table and re-initialize it with its new settings (and new data). I did notice that you mentioned _When I disable serverSide programmatically..._ - can you show how you are doing that?